# How can I tell a Racket program to load optional configuration code?

Tags: configuration, racket

I'm currently loading some configuration values into my program using

```
(require "config.rkt")
```

However, this requires that config.rkt is there. I'd like to be able to put some default values into my program and have Racket override them only if there's a local config file.

In Python I'd do something like :

```
try :
    from local_configs import MAIN_PATH, MAX_ENTRIES
except :
    MAIN_PATH = "~"
    MAX_ENTRIES = 20
```

What's the equivalent in Racket?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`dynamic-require`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Module_Names_and_Loading.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._dynamic-require%29%29) along with an exception handler ([`with-handlers`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/exns.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmore-scheme..rkt%29._with-handlers%29%29)).

Edit: my first proposed solution (using a failure thunk for `dynamic-require`) didn't handle the case where `"config.rkt"` didn't exist at all. Adding exception handling solves this.

Example:

```
#lang racket

;; try to require the given name, returning default on failure
(define (get-config name default)
  (with-handlers ([exn:fail? (λ (e) default)])
    (dynamic-require "config.rkt" name)))

(define main-path   (get-config 'main-path "~"))
(define max-entries (get-config 'max-entries 20))

;; just to show what the values are
(list main-path max-entries)
```

Here's a sample config file:

```
#lang racket

(provide main-path)

(define main-path "/home")
```

Running the first module with the sample config module produces a result like this:

```
'("/home" 20)
```

Comment: Thanks. This works perfectly for me in drracket, but when I try to compile it with raco, when I run it I get "standard-module-name-resolver: collection not found
  collection: "racket/lang"
  in collection directories:
"

Comment: I don't get that error on the latest version of Racket. Are you using an old version? It may be a bug that has been fixed already.